# Error: register 'sp' unsuitable for global register variables on this target

Tags: stm32, cpputest

I am playing around with a project for a STM32 µC. I use the [SW4STM32](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/sw4stm32.html) workbench and CubeMX on a Mac OSX system. My project itself is fine, everything compiles accordingly and behaves on the device as expected.

For a further learning purpose, I would like to implement unit tests using the [CppuUTest](https://cpputest.github.io/) framework. I have set up everything, got my test directories and a makefile to configure the MakefileWorker variables in place.

However, when executing the Makefile, I keep getting the error:

```
error: 
  register 'sp' unsuitable for global register variables on this target
```

This error originates from the file syscalls.c (which is a file generated by CubeMX). The line causing the error is:

```
register char * stack_ptr asm("sp");
```

After doing my research, it seems like there is no easy workaround to solve the issue. The source code is generated by Cube and works fine when compiling with the sw4stm32 toolchain (which is using a mcu gcc compiler).
However, the CppUTest toolchain is using clang, which cannot cope with global register variables (as the error says aswell).

My question here ist:

Has anyone of you had the same error yet or more experience in setting up CppUTest for a sw4stm32 project on an OSx system? Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

If you need more information / code snippets from me, I will gladly share it.

Thank you very much guys! Any help would be highly appreciated :-)

Cheers,
Tobi

Comment: Could you stick something like `asm("mov sp, %0" : "=r" (stack_ptr));` before each usage of stack_ptr (and remove the 'register' and 'asm' from the declaration)?  It's (really) ugly, but it might work.  Or even have an (inlinable) GetStackPtr() that contains this code?

Comment: I got the same error while compiling the code generated by CubeMX. It works fine on Atollic Studio, but when I use it in Sourcetrail, the error appears.